# Printing pattern of numbers

Tags: c++

Sample Input:

5 (rows)

Sample Output:

```
1
11
202
3003
40004
```

Input Format:

Single integer N denoting number of lines of the pattern.
Constraints:

N<=1000

my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;//no. of rows
    cout<<"1"<<endl;// printing  as default
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++) // loop for a row
    {

        for(int j=0;j<=i;j++)// loop for printing elements in a row
        {
            if(i>1) //insert zeros when from row having zeros
            {
                if(j==0 || j==i) //condition for printing non-zero number
                    cout<<i; 
                else
                {
                  for(int k=j+1;k<j;k++) //condition for prnting zeros
                    {
                        cout<<"0";//print zero
                    }
                }

            }
            else
                cout<<i; //only gets executed for i=1

        }
        cout<<endl;//printing new line after a row has ended printing
    }
}
```

//what am i doing wrong in the code my output is not printing zeros i am not obtaining the required pattern

Comment: check your condition for printing zeros and use a debugger

Comment: [The debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) is a programmer's best friend. It lets you see what you REALLY told the computer to do. You'll be hard pressed to find a better programming productivity tool, so the sooner you start using it, the sooner you can find time for whatever happens to be your second best friend.

Answer (score 1):

your code is pretty much correct except for the zero conditions. If the it's the end conditions i.e either j is 0 or i then print i else print 0;

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{ 
   int n;
   cin>>n;//no. of rows
   cout<<"1"<<endl;// printing  as default
   for(int i=1;i<n;i++) // loop for a row
   {

    for(int j=0;j<=i;j++)// loop for printing elements in a row
    {
      j==0 || j==i ? cout << i : cout << 0 ;
    }
    cout<<endl;//printing new line after a row has ended printing
 }
}
```

Comment: Or simply move `cout << i` around the inner loop (and fix bound).

Comment: Can you please explain?

Comment: `std::cout << i; for (int j = 0; j != i - 1; ++j) { std::cout << 0; } std::cout << i << std::endl;`

Comment: you actually did the same thing except you literally put cout << i in the start and the end xD

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 1; i < input; ++i){
    std::cout << i;
    for(int j = 1; j < i; ++j){
        std::cout << "0";
    }
    std::cout << i << "\n";
}
```

Explanation:

print i, then print as many zeros as the row were on, which is i-1 0's, then print i again.

Edit:

Since some people say I didn't answer OP's question.  Here's what you're doing wrong OP.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;//no. of rows
    cout<<"1"<<endl;// printing  as default
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++) // loop for a row
    {

        for(int j=0;j<=i;j++)// loop for printing elements in a row
        {
            if(i>1) //insert zeros when from row having zeros
            {
                if(j==0 || j==i) //condition for printing non-zero number
                    cout<<i; 
                else
                {
                   cout << "0"; //remove the for loop and replace with this
                }

            }
            else
                cout<<i; //only gets executed for i=1

        }
        cout<<endl;//printing new line after a row has ended printing
    }
}
```

I added a comment to line 26 in the else block, you were looping through each iteration.  This essentially added multiples of 0's to your output.

Comment: Why the downvote? It looks like the most straightforward solution.

Comment: @Ted Not only it's a code dump, but it also doesn't really answer the question of what's wrong with OP's code.

Comment: @CássioRenan There was already an explanation from another user when I made the post, I simply just gave a more elegant solution to the problem.  It's also not code dump when there's an explanation attached to the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
N = int(input())
def NumberPattern(N):
    for m in range(0,N):
        for n in range(1):
            if m == 0:
                print(1,end='')
            else: 
                print(m*(10**m)+m,end='')
        print('')
        
NumberPattern(N)
```